Pulumi Azure Native Provider: Error 404 when Adding WebAppApplicationSettings to Static Web App (SWA)
I'm working with the Pulumi Azure Native Provider to deploy infrastructure, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to add WebAppApplicationSettings to an Azure Static Web App (SWA). The Static Web App itself is created successfully, but when I attempt to create application settings for the SWA, I get a 404 error indicating that the resource cannot be found.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
Static Web App Creation
function createStaticSite(
  resourceGroupArgs: RessourceGroupArgs,
  userAssignedIdentity: managedidentity.UserAssignedIdentity
) {
  const rndSwaName = new random.RandomId("swa", {
    byteLength: 8,
    keepers: { keep: resourceGroupArgs.resourceGroupName },
  });

  return new web.StaticSite(
    `swa-`,
    {
      allowConfigFileUpdates: true,
      location: "West Europe",
      branch: "develop",
      name: rndSwaName.hex.apply((v) => `swa${v}`),
      repositoryUrl: "",
      resourceGroupName: resourceGroupArgs.resourceGroupName,
      sku: {
        name: "Standard",
        tier: "Standard",
      },
      stagingEnvironmentPolicy: web.StagingEnvironmentPolicy.Enabled,
      identity: {
        type: "UserAssigned",
        userAssignedIdentities: userAssignedIdentity.id.apply((id) => getId(id)),
      },
      buildProperties: {},
    },
    { dependsOn: [userAssignedIdentity] }
  );
}

    const staticSite = createStaticSite(rgArgs, userAssignedIdentity);
  const setting = createWebApplicationSetting(staticSite, rgArgs);

Adding Application Settings to the Static Web App
Next, I try to add application settings:
  function createWebApplicationSetting(
  staticApp: web.StaticSite,
  resourceGroupArgs: RessourceGroupArgs
) {
  return new web.WebAppApplicationSettings(
    "staticWebApplicationSetting",
    {
      name: staticApp.name,
      resourceGroupName: resourceGroupArgs.resourceGroupName,
      properties: {
        ClientId:"...",
        ClientSecret: "...",
      },
    },
    {
      dependsOn: [staticApp],
    }
  );
}

Error:
I consistently encounter this error when applying the application settings:
 azure-native:web:WebAppApplicationSettings (staticWebApplicationSetting):
error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ResourceNotFound" Message="The Resource '' under resource group '' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix"

Diagnostics So Far

The static web app creation itself is logged successfully (seen in Azure...).
I've ensured that the WebAppApplicationSettings depends on the static web
app using dependsOn.

Question
Why am I getting a 404 error when trying to add application settings to the static web app using the Azure Native Provider in Pulumi? Is there something I'm missing about the correct way to reference the static web app resource?

Use their own set of APIs and resources, and the WebAppApplicationSettings resource belongs to the Azure App Service (Web Apps) family, not Static Web Apps.

In Azure, Static Web Apps have their own configuration and settings API, and do not use WebAppApplicationSettings like traditional App Service Web Apps.

Set environment variables either through the buildProperties or other environment settings at the Static Web App level.

function createStaticSite(
  resourceGroupArgs: RessourceGroupArgs,
  userAssignedIdentity: managedidentity.UserAssignedIdentity
) {
  const rndSwaName = new random.RandomId("swa", {
    byteLength: 8,
    keepers: { keep: resourceGroupArgs.resourceGroupName },
  });

  return new web.StaticSite(
    `swa-`,
    {
      allowConfigFileUpdates: true,
      location: "West Europe",
      branch: "develop",
      name: rndSwaName.hex.apply((v) => `swa${v}`),
      repositoryUrl: "",
      resourceGroupName: resourceGroupArgs.resourceGroupName,
      sku: {
        name: "Standard",
        tier: "Standard",
      },
      stagingEnvironmentPolicy: web.StagingEnvironmentPolicy.Enabled,
      identity: {
        type: "UserAssigned",
        userAssignedIdentities: userAssignedIdentity.id.apply((id) => getId(id)),
      },
      buildProperties: {
        appSettings: {
          "ClientId": "...",
          "ClientSecret": "...",
        },
      },
    },
    { dependsOn: [userAssignedIdentity] }
  );
}


The buildProperties.appSettings object allows you to define key-value pairs that will act as environment variables this is similar to what you are trying to achieve with WebAppApplicationSettings.

Result:

PS C:\Users\*******\Desktop\ts_test\test2> pulumi up
Previewing update (dev):

     Type                                  Name                                Plan
 +   pulumi:pulumi:Stack                   myproject-dev                       create
 +   ├─ random:index:RandomId              swa                                 create
 +   ├─ azure-native:managedidentity:UserAssignedIdentity myidentity            create
 +   ├─ azure-native:web:StaticSite        teststaticapp01                        create
 +   └─ pulumi:providers:random            default                             create

Resources:
    + 5 to create

Updating (dev):

     Type                                  Name                                Status
 +   pulumi:pulumi:Stack                   myproject-dev                       created
 +   ├─ random:index:RandomId              swa                                 created
 +   ├─ azure-native:managedidentity:UserAssignedIdentity myidentity            created
 +   ├─ azure-native:web:StaticSite        teststaticapp01                        created
 +   └─ pulumi:providers:random            default                             created

Outputs:
    swaName: "teststaticapp01"

Resources:
    + 5 created

Duration: 30s

Permalink: https://app.pulumi.com/myorg/myproject/dev/updates/1

